# Where can I find various existing ontologies regarding certain aspects?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology

I need to create – possibly, by reusing various (parts of) existing ontologies – an ontological model regarding certain aspects – data communication, data processing, data storage, etc. – regarding a distributed system (platform, framework,...) used in the context of big data. Significant concepts, relations, restrictions, individuals should be considered as examples for a real software product like Hadoop or Git Large File Storage might be taking into account. Do someone know if there are ontologies that describes the system for one of the above or any other distributed system?

Comment: Wrong place to ask such questions, see the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a specific vocabulary for that, but there are sites out there that can help you find what you need, e.g. http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/